# help with literal syntax - not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep trying to call getMonthDay function. I am passing a pubDate parameter and keep getting error - Break on ErrorXCopyDisableContinue
this.getMonthDay is not a function

Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert = console.log; 


    var ns = {

        init : function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/calendar/RSSSyndicator.aspx?type=N&number=15&category=8-0%2c4-0%2c6-0%2c10-0%2c7-0%2c17-0%2c16-0%2c9-0%2c5-0%2c3-0%2c2-0&department=3&numdays=31&ics=Y&rsstitle=Annandale+-+Event+Listing&rssid=11',
                success: this.loaded                
            });
        }, 

        loaded: function(data){

            // Find item from the RSS document and iterate over reach one.
            $(data).find('item').each(function(i, value){

                // Set the title and get rid of all chars including and between ()
                var title = $(this).find('title').text().replace(/\w+\s+\(.*?\)/, "");

                var link = $(this).find('link').text();
                var pubDate = $(this).find('pubDate').text();
                alert(title); 
                alert(link);
                alert(pubDate);

                test = this.getMonthDay(pubDate);


                $('#events').append("<p>" + title + "<br/>" + link + "</p>");

            });

        //  var t = items[0].getElementsByTagName('title');
        //  alert(t[0].firstChild.nodeValue);

        }, 



        getMonthDay : function(pubDate){

            var d = new Date(pubDate);

            d.month = d.getMonth();
            var months = ["January", "February", "March", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
            var month = months[d.month]
            var newMonthDay = month + " " + d.getDay();

            return newMonthDay;


        }

    }



    ns.init();




});
```

Comment: I am calling the method correctly?  test = this.getMonthDay(pubDate);

Comment: Nope. That's the error. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually 2 issues here.  The most immediate/local is that `this` refers to that `<item>` element you're on in the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop, we can fix that by holding a reference outside to `this`, like so:

```
var self = this;
```

Then inside the function, use `self.getMonthDay(pubDate);`.  Second, after that's fixed...even then `this` isn't what you want, it refers to the `options` object you passed to [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  To remedy this, you need the [`context` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) there to maintain `this` being `ns` as well, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert = console.log; 
    var ns = {
        init : function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/calendar/RSSSyndicator.aspx?type=N&number=15&category=8-0%2c4-0%2c6-0%2c10-0%2c7-0%2c17-0%2c16-0%2c9-0%2c5-0%2c3-0%2c2-0&department=3&numdays=31&ics=Y&rsstitle=Annandale+-+Event+Listing&rssid=11',
                context: this,          //add this!
                success: this.loaded                
            });
        }, 
        loaded: function(data){
            var self = this;           //maintain a reference to this
            $(data).find('item').each(function(i, value){
                var title = $(this).find('title').text().replace(/\w+\s+\(.*?\)/, "");
                var link = $(this).find('link').text();
                var pubDate = $(this).find('pubDate').text();
                var test = self.getMonthDay(pubDate);
                $('#events').append("<p>" + title + "<br/>" + link + "</p>");
            });
        }, 
        getMonthDay : function(pubDate){
            var d = new Date(pubDate);
            d.month = d.getMonth();
            var months = ["January", "February", "March", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
            var month = months[d.month]
            var newMonthDay = month + " " + d.getDay();
            return newMonthDay;
        }
    }
    ns.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `this.getMonthDay` from within the callback you're passing to `.each()`. At that point, `this` is a completely different context. Instead, consider something like:

```
loaded: function(data){

    var ns = this;

    // Find item from the RSS document and iterate over reach one.
    $(data).find('item').each(function(i, value){

        // Set the title and get rid of all chars including and between ()
        var title = $(this).find('title').text().replace(/\w+\s+\(.*?\)/, "");

        var link = $(this).find('link').text();
        var pubDate = $(this).find('pubDate').text();
        alert(title); 
        alert(link);
        alert(pubDate);

        test = ns.getMonthDay(pubDate);


        $('#events').append("<p>" + title + "<br/>" + link + "</p>");

    });

//  var t = items[0].getElementsByTagName('title');
//  alert(t[0].firstChild.nodeValue);

},
```

Note the creation of an alias (`ns`) for `this`, which can then continue to refer to that object regardless of what objects/contexts might later come into play.

Comment: I just made the update to the ns for this. I'm gettign - ns.getMonthDay is not a function

Comment: @steve - this is only half the issue, while correct it's not everything you need, `this` is lost before then...see my answer for an explanation :)

Comment: Just got it work Nick and Votey. You  both are  js rockstars. Btw, would you have used literal syntax for what I'm trying to accomplish? I'm pretty much a newb right now.

Comment: @steve - I don't usually, that's not to say it's just not useful, just totally depends on the situation as to what I'm going with :)

Comment: ok, i just want to make sure i'm not making things harder for myself than they should.